# Make sum with two files but once time per line

Tags: ksh

I have two files. In one file I have a random date per line and in the other file I have a number per line, this means:

File1:

```
2018/06/24 14:17:19
2018/06/15 17:24:50
2018/07/15 10:25:29
```

File2:

```
5938
1234
4567
```

So, I want to reading the two files and add the number (in seconds) to the dates, one time per line.

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'


for i in `cat fechas_prueba.txt`
do
        for j in `cat duraciones.txt` 
        do
                echo "$i - $j"
                newDate=$(date -d "$i $j seconds" "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
                echo $newDate >> sum_dates.txt
        done
done
```

I want that the first line of file1 sum with the first line of file2, the second line with the second line... This means:

```
2018/06/24 15:56:17
2018/06/15 17:45:24
2018/07/15 11:41:36
```

However, I get the following:

```
2018/06/24 15:56:17
2018/06/24 14:37:53
2018/06/24 15:33:26
2018/06/15 19:03:48
2018/06/15 17:45:24
2018/06/15 18:40:57
2018/07/15 12:04:27
2018/07/15 10:46:03
2018/07/15 11:41:36
```

So, How I can to only sum line1 with line1, line2 with line2, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have ksh, so I can not test the solution for your environment. You can try something like `join file1 file2 | while IFS= read -r day time offset;...`

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like that, providing your date are in date.txt, the second to add to those dates are in second.txt and that you want the final result to be in finaldate.txt.

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Opening finaldate.txt for writing on file descriptor 3
exec 3>./finaldate.txt

# Read simultaneously the OriginalDate from file descriptor 4 and
# SecondToAdd from file descriptor 5
while read -u 4 OriginalDate && read -u 5 SecondToAdd; do
        FinalDateInSecond=$(($(date -d "$OriginalDate" +"%s")+$SecondToAdd))
        FinalDate=$(date -d @"$FinalDateInSecond" +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        # Printing the result on file descriptor 3
        print -u 3 $FinalDate
# Having date.txt being read on file descriptor 4 while second.txt being
# read on file descriptor 5
done 4<date.txt 5<second.txt
```

Hope it can help

Comment: Hi Andre!

I just prove your code and works fine!

But, Could you explain me the code? I don't understand it very well...

Very very thanks!
Regards.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my post with some comments. Don't hesitate if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi again,

One stupid question... What is a file descriptor? I've searched in Google but I don't understand it very well.

For other hand, if I understand it well, the command "exec 3>.finaldate.txt" redirects the result to the file, isn't it?

Always I had seen this command with "1" and "2" parameter but I hadn't never seen it with "3".

Thanks!
Regards.

Comment: That's quite a question ! :) Unfortunately not one that can be answered in a short fashion. You might find this link easier to understand : https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/file-descriptor.htm